# VOCevaldet.m produces incorrect mAP

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, caffe, object-detection, darknet

I attempt to compute the mAP of YOLO_v2 and SSD on the VOC2007 test set using VOCevaldet.m, but in both cases I reach lower mAPs than the values reported in the papers.

To produce the detection txt files in VOC format (a file per class), I use the command ./darknet detector valid cfg/voc.data cfg/yolo-voc.cfg weights/yolo-voc.weights for YOLO in darknet, and the python script score_ssd_pascal.py for SSD in Caffe.

What am I missing? Why don't I get the same results as in the papers?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the weights shared by the authors or your own trained ones? Can you post the mAP numbers you get?

Comment: Yes. I downloaded the configuration files and weights from their sites.
I get 68.3% (instead of 76.8%) for YOLO_v2 and 71.9% (instead of 77.2%) for SSD.

Comment: how did you obtain the test images?

Comment: For SSD, when you run score_ssd_pascal.py directly, do you get the desired mAP?

Comment: Yes. Running score_ssd_pascal.py yields a mAP of 77.2%. The test images are those of VOC2007.